# variables inside variables

Tags: php, syntax, variables

Ok this might sound like a dumb question but bear with me.  I am trying to make it so that when people go to example.php?id=1, example.php?id=2, example.php?id=3 etc they see different data called from an included file filling in the blanks.

I have a variable called $offername  and I want to display $offer1name, $offer2name, $offer3name in that space, depending on what $_GET['id'] says.  Ideally, when someone goes to example.php?id=2, $offername will equal $offer2name.

I want to do something like this:

$offername = $offer.$_GET['id'].name

But of course that doesn't work.  What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a generated variable name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130240/can-i-use-a-generated-variable-name-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$var = 'offer' . $_GET['id'] . 'name';
$offername = $$var;
```

See the page on [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for more.

Comment: don't forget to validate $_GET['id'] and check whether $var is set.

Comment: So does the following: $offername = ${'offer' . $_GET['id'] . 'name'};

Comment: Variable variables are my least favourite feature of any language - they are a clear sign that an array or hash should be used instead.

Answer (score 5):

A much cleaner solution is to just use multidimensional arrays.

e.g., instead of

```
$offername = ${offer.$_GET['id'].name};
```

use

```
$offername = $offer[$_GET['id']]['name'];
```

and define $offer like so:

```
$offer = array(
  1 => array(
    'name' => 'firstoffer',
  ),
  2 => array(
    'name' => 'secondoffer',
  ),
  3 => array(
    'name' => 'thirdoffer',
  ),
);
```

I find variable variables difficult to read, and most of the time when I see them used, an array would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can use variable variables

So you can have `$offer_variable_name = 'offer' . $_GET['id'] . 'name';`

And then use something like `$offername = $$offer_variable_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can in addition to the other solutions do:

```
$offername = ${'offer' . $_GET['id'] . 'name'};
```