# Appending a value of a variable to a variable name?

Tags: php, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use a generated variable name in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130240/can-i-use-a-generated-variable-name-in-php)

Am stuck here!

```
$part_one = "abc";
$v = "one";

echo $part_???; // should output "abc"
```

How do I modify ??? to reference $v?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
echo ${'part_'.$v};
// or
$var = 'part_'.$v;
echo $$var;
```

Comment: Why would this ever be useful?  Just curious...

Comment: Since variable can also be used to call functions (`${'part_'.$v}()` would call the `abc` function), you can use this to compact algorithms where only the name of the function may vary. Take the `imagecreatefrom…` functions for example: Just get the image type, append it to "imagecreatefrom" and call that function: `$func = "imagecreatefrom".$type; $func($filename);`.

Comment: Another example is: `$sides = array('front' => array(1,2), 'back' => array(2,3)); foreach ($sides as $side_name => $side_value) { ${'side_' . $side_name} = array_sum($side_value); };` At this point, you have `$side_front = 3` and `$side_back = 5`. Very useful to not repeat code that may work well in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

$_part$v;? maybe idk. I know you can do this:

```
$vname="variable";
$$vname="hello";
echo $variable;

//WOULD output "hello"
```

try this:

```
$name="_part";
$name=$name . $v;
$$name=$value;
```