# Use variable contents inside variable name with php?

Tags: php, variables, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appending a value of a variable to a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774975/appending-a-value-of-a-variable-to-a-variable-name)

I can't figure out the syntax at all and have searched far and wide.

I would like to do this:

```
$uni = "ntu";
$selectedntu = "something";

echo $selected$uni;
// output should be the same as
echo $selectedntu;
```

In other words I'd like to use the contents of the second variable $uni to join onto the first variable's name. $selectedntu has been set with a foreach loop, but I can't figure out how to reference the two variables together in php.

Comment: Nevermind I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774975/appending-a-value-of-a-variable-to-a-variable-name

${'selected'.$uni};

Comment: Have you also read the manual chapter about [arrays](http://php.net/array) yet? Because that's one of the common causes for newcomers to inquire about var varnames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct the string and use a variable variable `$$`

```
$uni = "ntu";
$selected = "something";

$new_variable = $selected . $uni; 
echo $$new_variable;
```

// Or..per your googleing..purely for reference for others later

```
$uni = "ntu";
$selected = "something";

echo ${$selected . $uni};
```

Comment: `${"selected".$uni}` is what you were after.  Otherwise you would have to define `$selected="selected";` first.

Comment: Yep cheers, I didn't want to / need to define another variable so  echo ${$var.$var2}; worked perfectly.