# How to appending variable to a variable name

Tags: php, variables

I have a similar problem with this topic
[Appending a value of a variable to a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774975/appending-a-value-of-a-variable-to-a-variable-name)

but the answer not solve my problem,
i have variable,$item->ans_cont1 ..... to $item->ans_cont34
tried

```
for($i=1;$i<35;$i++) {      
  $inputval = 'item->ans_cont'.$i;
  echo $$inputval;  //output is empty
  echo ${'item->ans_cont'.$i};  //output is empty
}
```

but not work,is it "->" arrow problem?how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: `$$inputval` consider as variable. which is undefined. in short you are echoing the 34 variables without assigning.

Comment: for($i=1;$i<35;$i++) {      $inputval = $item->ans_cont.$i;echo $inputval; echo $$inputval;}

Comment: FYI...  You will save yourself grief by learning to use arrays instead: `echo $item->ans_cont[$i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$item` is an Object so you have to call its attribute:

```
$inputval = $item->{'ans_cont'.$i};
// Or 
$inputval = 'ans_cont'.$i;
echo $item->$inputval;
```