# PHP how to put the following in a loop

Tags: php

I've been trying for 2 hours now and I cannot seem to get it right.

How do I put the following in a loop and create unique variables for each output:

```
$valueEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql, $_POST['Email']);
$valuePassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql, $_POST['Password']);
$valueConfirmPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql, $_POST['ConfirmPassword']);
```

Comment: You can't put simple variables into loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand, what you really need, but if I understood correctly you can use something like this:

```
$array = //array with all your inputs
[
    'Email',
    'Password'
];
for($i=0; $i<count($array);$i++) {
    ${'value'.$array[$i]}=mysqli_real_escape_string($sql, $_POST[$array[$i]]);
}
echo $valueEmail." ".$valuePassword; // Works!
```

You can read more here [Appending a value of a variable to a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774975/appending-a-value-of-a-variable-to-a-variable-name)

Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks that works! 
Also, what if my array looks like this:   `$formOptions = array('Email', 'Password');`

Comment: By the way: Sorry for my vague question but i'm glad you got it haha

Comment: @NielsvanOsch well, your array can look both like `array()` or like `[...]` there is no difference ;) If this answer helped you, you can mark it as best :)

Comment: what array do you recommend?

Comment: @NielsvanOsch don't think there is any difference in new versions of PHP but I always use `[]`. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26652262/4402190 :)