# PHP generate arrays in loop

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

I have these loop statement to generate arrays labeled with z variable. array will be sent to ajax to be displayed in HTML page.

```
    for($z=0;$z<5;$z++){    
        $billsum = $bills['amount'];
         $bill['$z'] = [$billsum];      
    }
```

How can I generate arrays such as $bill0,$bill1,$bill2,$bill3,...etc

Comment: remove the `'` around $z: `$bill[$z] = $billsum;` (and the [] - or do you really want _another_ nested array in there?)

Comment: you are aware, that $billsum will allways be the same??

Comment: since you accepted an answer below (which is correct) I just wanted to tell you, that it's a very bad idea to have variables named $bill0, $bill1, ... This is what arrays are for!

Comment: @Jeff would you please explain. Thx

Comment: it's far better and more practical to have an array `$bills` that contains each bill in `$bill[0], $bill[1],..`. (or maybe you want an array with only billsums, then call it `$billsums[1], ..`

Comment: @Jeff I understand your words, but I would like to know why it is bad technically?

Comment: some reads: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343949/variable-variables-bad-practice-to-use, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135192/php-how-can-i-create-variable-names-within-a-loop especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135494/4830296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($z=0;$z<5;$z++){    
        $billsum = $bills['amount'];
        ${'bill'.$z} = [$billsum];      
}
```

So, now you will have arrays like $bill0,$bill1,$bill2,$bill3...

Answer (score 2):

`$z` shouldn't be inside quotes.

```
for($z=0;$z<5;$z++){    
        $billsum = $bills['amount'];
        $bill[$z] = [$billsum];      
}
```

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: bill0

Comment: What line is that?

Comment: I'm sending the array back to ajax. the correct way is marked already thx