# How could I construct a variable name from another variable?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Construct a PHP variable name based on other variable values and static text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817922/construct-a-php-variable-name-based-on-other-variable-values-and-static-text)

```
$value = '200';
$_200 = 'other';
```

How could I echo the contents of the second variable, getting its name from the first variable? So basically read the value of `$value`, prepend an `_` and use it as a variable name.

Comment: [Variable variables in the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 3):

Same as always.

```
echo ${'_'.$value};
```

Comment: Got knowledge form you , Thanks !