# PHP variable in variable

Tags: php, variables, global

I have set an array in my config file that I use global in my functions.
This works fine, but now I want to pass the name of this array as a @param in my function.

```
// in config file:
$album_type_arr = array("appartamento", "villa");   

global $album_type_arr; // pull in from db_config
echo $album_type_arr[0];

function buildmenu($name) {
    $test = global $name . "_arr";
    echo $test[0];
}
buildmenu("album_type");
```

Comment: Can't you just pass your array into your function directly?  `buildmenu($album_type_arr);`

Comment: maybe but I need that name for other stuff, values etc. tnx anyway.

Comment: duplicate of [Can I use a generated variable name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130240/can-i-use-a-generated-variable-name-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for variable variables:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
function buildmenu($name) {
    $test = $name . "_arr";
    global ${$test};
    echo ${$test}[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)". This works:

```
function buildmenu($name) {
   global ${$name. '_arr'};
   $test = ${$name. '_arr'};
   echo $test[0];
}
```