# php get the variable name from other variable

Tags: php, variable-variables

look at this simple script please

```
$c1 = $_GET[c1];
$c2 = $_GET[c2];
$c3 = $_GET[c3];
$c4 = $_GET[c4];
$c5 = $_GET[c5];
for($i = 1;$i <=5;$i++)
{
    echo $c{$i};//or something else here :/
}
```

how can i print tha values of variables?

Thanks

Comment: If you are defining the variables, use an array instead.  Could someone explain why so many are suggesting alternatives to a plain-old array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a generated variable name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130240/can-i-use-a-generated-variable-name-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#97222) some good examples in the variable page. Read that and take a look at the examples.

Also, below is your piece of code fixed so it can work:

```
<?php

$c1 = $_GET[c1];
$c2 = $_GET[c2];
$c3 = $_GET[c3];
$c4 = $_GET[c4];
$c5 = $_GET[c5];
for($i = 1;$i <=5;$i++)
{
    echo ${"c".$i};
}
```

Comment: This is not a good thing to advise the guy to do. This is a case where arrays are the most appropriate answer; why tell him to use variable variables?

Comment: He wanted variable variables (probably because in `$c1`, `$c2` etc checks the $_GET contents. If he would have asked for other solutions, I would suggest others, but it seems to me this questions is about **variable variables**.

Comment: This answer is more correct, but recommending arrays is better. In cases like these, I feel that the best answers are a merging of yours and @Kieren Johnstone: they offer the solution to the question at hand, but also make a point of saying that it's really not good practice. Regardless, +1 to you both xP

Answer (score 3):

You should use an array rather than individual variables.

For reference:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3):

If these values are closely related, consider changing their name attribute in your HTML/form.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="c[]" />
    <input type="text" name="c[]" />
    ...
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_GET['c'])) {
        foreach($_GET['c'] as $c) {
            echo $c;
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way of doing it, using Arrays, rather than individual variables, which works easier and more efficiently.

```
<?php
$array['c1'] = $_GET['c1'];
$array['c2'] = $_GET['c2'];
$array['c3'] = $_GET['c3'];
$array['c4'] = $_GET['c4'];
$array['c5'] = $_GET['c5'];
for ($i=1; $i>=5; $i++) {
    echo $array['c' . $i];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [PHP variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) is what you are looking for.

```
$i = "c1";
print $$i;
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to construct correct values for 'i'.

Answer (score -2):

This should work..

```
 foreach($_GET as $id => $value){
      echo $value;
 }
```

even though this prints out every $_GET.