# Merge variables

Tags: php, merge

We have `$id` and `$title` variables, which everytime change.

For each `$id` we should create a new variable `$temp_title_%id%`, and give to it `$title`'s value.

Like:

```
$id = 10;
$title = 'Hello people!';
$temp_title_10 = 'Hello people!';
```

Tryed this (doesn't work):

```
$temp_title_ . $id = $title;
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a generated variable name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130240/can-i-use-a-generated-variable-name-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using an array instead? An array is a much better way of storing multiple values. Much, much, ***much*** better.

```
$title_array = array();

$id = 10;
$title = 'Hello people!';
$title_array[$id] = $title;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to persist your variables, it would probably be better to place them in an array if your `$id` variable will always be an integer.

```
$persistence_array = array();

while (some_requirement) {
    $id = ...;
    $title = ...;
    $persistence_array[$id] = $title;
}
```

If `$id` might also contain alpha-numeric data, then you could always use a hash / dictionary in the same way (with a small amount of additional logic you could even store multiple values for the same id).

**DON'T DO THIS:** If you absolutely **must** have variables then you can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) But please, don't.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bad idea to do what you're trying to do, but here's how to do it anyways:

```
$GLOBALS["temp_title_".$id]=$title;
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
$varname="temp_title_".$id;
$$varname=$title;
```

The most correct way to do what I think you're trying to do would be to use an array:

```
// Somewhere in the PHP script:
$an_array=array();

// To assign:
$an_array[$id]=$title;

// To retrieve:
echo $an_array[$id];
```

Comment: The first approach is dangerous.  It will not work inside a function and will mess with global variables.

Comment: I agree... its a bad idea. I cant think of a use case where it would even make sense.

Comment: @Sebastián: I know, and that's why I listed a second approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$metavariable = "temp_title_".$id;
$$metavariable = $title;  // note the $$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
${'temp_title_' . $id} = $title;
echo $temp_title_10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use variable variable of PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
$variable = $title.'_'.$id
$$variable = 'hello, world!'
```